# How to convert existing files' encoding to UTF-8 in eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, encoding, eclipse-luna

I have many files of various types with different encodings. Ideally I want to change the encoding of all files of a specific type to another encoding (for example change the encoding of all PHP files to UTF-8).

I know I can change a specific file's encoding from its properties menu, but I was wondering if there is a way to apply the change to *all* files without iterating manually through each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change all files with one extension, you can go to `Window > Preferences > General > Content types`, press on `Select text` dropdown and select the language that you want to change the enconding.

After that, in `File associations` section choose all the extensions that you want to change and in the bottom of the page, on `Default encoding` input box, write the encoding that you want to use and press Update after that.

For example, to change PHP in the Content Types you need to select `PHP Content Type`, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this updates the default encoding for files created in the future. It does not update the encoding of existing ones.